# How does a domain beginning with www.uk get resolved?

Tags: domain-name-system, virtualhost

I have  seen domains such as www.uk.domain.mobi. Is there no restriction in terms of what is allowed after www?

Can I call a subdomain anything I like and is there no dot-separated word limit?

Comment: Doesn't matter what the beginning is - resolution starts from the end (.mobi)

Answer (score 12):

No. At the very least after the second level domain (`domain.mobi`) you are completely free to choose additional subdomain names. Even `www` is such an arbitrary name. Of course, your local laws might restrict you, and there are some technical restrictions:

- max.127 levels
- max 253 characters for the complete name
- 63 characters for a sub-name (like `www`).

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) for more infos.

Comment: In case it's not clear from Sven's otherwise-excellent answer, you're parsing the domain name from the wrong end.  the `.mobi` end is tightly-fixed, highly-regulated by IANA; but as you go further and further towards the beginning of the string, to the `www.` end, it becomes more and more a matter of choice for the domain registrant.

Comment: Yep, I didnt know this. 8+ years in IT. Am suitably ashamed :(

Answer (score 4):

Simply put (in addition to restrictions mentioned in other answer):

```
www.uk.domain.mobi
|      |     |
|      |     .mobi - TLD (Top-level domain) => Currently ~253 to pick from
|      |
|      domain.mobi - Domain name => Can be anything that hasn't been registered
|
www.uk. - Sub-domain(s) => Can be anything you want after registering the above.
```

[List of TLDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains)

> Can I call a subdomain anything I like and is there no dot-separated word limit?

Yes, once in control of the DNS records you can create subdomains, [sub-subdomains](http://techtitbits.com/2008/07/how-to-set-up-a-sub-subdomain/), sub-sub-subdomains, etc.

Comment: So what is www then? An arbitrary subdomain name?

Comment: Yes, it stands for "world wide web" and is not needed for the browser to know that http:// maps to port 80 by default. Just a relic from the past.. there are arguments both for ([1](http://labs.phurix.net/articles/yes-www),[2](http://www.yes-www.org/)) and against ([1](http://no-www.org/)) keeping it. Serverfault opts for redirecting to a naked (no-www) domain name.